# How do I define a component in a slot which as a prop which is defined in the child component

Tags: vue.js

Let's say I have three components: Alpha, Bravo and Charlie.

Which looks like this:

**Alpha.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="alpha">
        <bravo>
            <template slot="card">
                <charlie></charlie>
            </template>
        </bravo>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Bravo.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="bravo">
        <slot name="card" v-for="result in results" :result="result"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            results: [1, 2, 3]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Charlie.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>{{ result }}</h1>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: [
        'result'
    ]
}
</script>
```

How can I pass the result prop to Charlie while defining it in a slot in Alpha?

The idea behind this is that Bravo contains a lot of shared logic. There are different variations of Alpha which may contain a different card for the slot (but will always have a result prop.)

At the moment when running that, the result prop is not being parsed to the Charlie component and an undefined error is occurring (there are probably several wrong things with the example but I hope it demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve.)

Comment: `Bravo` is not a valid component here.

Comment: @Bert in what sense?

Comment: You may not have a slot as a root element, and you may not have multiple root elements.

Comment: Ultimately though, what you want is to define a scoped slot in Bravo. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots

Comment: Thanks @Bert and I've updated the question to reflect the errors you've highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is solution for your case

**Alpha.vue**

```
<template>
<bravo>
<template slot="card" slot-scope="{ result }">
<charlie :result="result"></charlie>
</template>
</bravo>
</template>
```

And you should wrap your slots in Bravo.vue

[Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots)

Comment: The Charlie component needs to be defined in the Alpha component not Bravo

Comment: @David Update answer

Comment: That's done it, looks like I wasn't including the result prop in the Alpha component, thanks!